# Appending a new column to existing dataframe Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So this time I'm having a problem with a.) converting a list of string values to a Spark column, and b.) appending this column to an existing DataFrame. I think the biggest problem is that I don't think I understand the type of data structure that is required for conversion into Spark Column. Anyway, I would like to append the following List of values (`subjectIDs`) to an existing DF using Scala:

```
val subjectIDs = List("e03", "a01", "b03", "e01", "c02")
```

Then when I run this line...:

```
val addSubjectIDs = udf(() => subjectIDs.toDF())
```

...I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:755)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3176)
  ... 54 elided
```

Ideally, after correct conversion I would like to do the following:

```
val dataset = examples.withColumn("subject_id", addSubjectIDs())
```

And obtain the DF of this shape:

```
dataset.show

+-------+-----------+
|  score| subject_id|
+-------+-----------+
|   5032|        e03|
|   1959|        a01|
|   5629|        b03|
|   5666|        e01|
|   9325|        c02|
+-------+-----------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to do a join here on your new dataset?  What is the rule for matching the new columns, if you just want them used in order use the zip function

Comment: @philantrovert thanks for pointing this out - I couldn't find a related topic.

Comment: @puhlen thanks, zip will probably be an approach to use.